# Windows 10 - AMD radeon 8670M - no hdmi output

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, hdmi

i have one problem with older device. it will not output video to the HDMI

DEVICE INFO:
HP pavilion 15-n008sc - says in the back
with intel graphics 4000 and amd readeon 8670M

- in hp support says it should have nvidia, but it has amd so probably it is 15-n008sr
- also have amd sticker on it
- win 10 64 bit fresh install (before it had win 8)

Already tried:

- multiple hdmi devices, 2 x TV, 1x monitor with hdmi
- multiple hdmi cables
- multiple drivers for GPUs
- change power settings for system

EXPECTED RESULT: to see video from laptop in tv

POSSIBLE PROBLEM:
something with drivers. If i try to install intel hd raphics drivers, it show (oops no video card found). If i try to install AMD adrenalin 2020 auto detect (also says no graphic card)
If i try to install AMD driver for radeon hd 8600 series it instaled succesfuly.
in devmgmt it shows both GPUs, when intel is disabled cannot use WIN + P to set mode of presentation.
When used win+ p to e.g. duplicate screen tv looks like it detects but after one second again no input error. The INTEL GPU software do not detects hdmi if plugged (show only integrated display)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hard drive issue, so check the soldering and stuff. I mean, if on win 8 it worked, then it is not a hard drive issue.

Have you tried looking in the BIOS? The NTFS formatting could have caused some problems that made the HDMI output go 'nill'.

Unfortunately, i am mainly familiar with ASUS and Lenovo BIOS, and i am not too good at win 8 and AMD based CPU's. I am good with Win 10 and Intel CPU's.

Comment: The bios is very clean, there are no options almost. It also worked in windws 10 but probably before 3 or 4 months

Comment: That makes it very confusing. Because it worked in Windows 10 before the issue, then it either is a hardware issue (maybe is broke?) or it is a virus (highly improbable since the antivirus would detect it). I have also looked at the basic schematics of the device, and the internals of it online and i see no weak spot. I really cannot say anything either than the fact that it could be hardware or a virus.

Comment: Well, i could try to make fresh install of win 10, but first i will try to uninstall some updates

Comment: Yeah try and do that. But just look at the board of the laptop, and look everywhere on the board. Then uninstall the updates. My other suggestion that i just remembered is to use a Linux system and see what happens. By doing that, you can see if it is hardware of a Windoes issue.